# Difference between making a new Outlook PST and using built-in archive (to PST) function?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

Background:  I'm using the latest Outlook within Office 365.  My email provider is a 3rd party who I pay for POP3 service.  This is for personal use and NOT attached to a company Exchange system.  My primary email account's PST file grows by about 6 GB per year.  Currently it is nearly 20 GB.  I want to be able to search old emails.

Question:  What's the practical difference between me using Outlook's built-in archive function (which makes a new PST file anyway, as I recall from a long time ago) versus me just closing this PST file and starting a new one manually (which would keep PST filenames as I choose them)?    Does Outlook search within its "archive" PST files?  And if I use AutoArchive I think will it keep making new "archive1" and "archive2" etc. PST files every so often but I can rename them in Outlook, else manually, so I can call them "01-01-2019-to-12-31-2019.pst" (example) which is obviously more helpful if I need to manually open them for searching in the future?

And if do have to manually open an old PST file to search for an email within it, how do  I tell Outlook not to drop new mail every few minutes into my old PST file?

Comment: There is no difference.  Any .PST file is considered to be an archive of your emails.  Outlook will search through whichever folders you tell it to.

Comment: How do you configure it to search through "whichever folders you tell it to"?   I'm referring to searching via the "search current mailbox" textbox close to the top right of my screen, if that makes a difference, but I'm willing to search a different way.

Comment: There is a drop down list of options next to the search field.

Comment: @Ramhound, even if I set that to "all outlook items" I believe it only searches archive folders which it has created and which exist in an "archive" node within the navigation option on the left.  In my case, I don't have any archive node on the left side so Outlook would not automatically just scan every PST file it can find (or even know where they exist on my hard drive).  This is where my knowledge of how things work is weak.  I don't understand how Outlook comes to know how many archive PST files exist, etc.  There is very little information about this and custom naming them, etc.

Comment: If you want your Outlook to searches archive PST file, you need to firstly open the archive PST files via File > Open & Export > Open Outlook Data File. Then select "all outlook items".

Comment: Aidan, that is as I thought, thanks (that Outlook won't search a closed file automatically). I appreciate this confirmation.  But when archive files are open, do you know how to stop Outlook from dropping new mail in those folders instead of the new ones?  They both have rules that say "drop the new mail here".